# how to trigger an @api.onchange by changing records name?

Tags: python, xml, model, odoo, odoo-13

I'm having an issue right now with the behavior of api.onchange with a Many2one Field, Right now i have a code that generetes a record of 'orders.products.attributes', I need to trigger the api.onchange when the name of the record changes, for example:

[Example of when to trigger api.onchange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRVnx.png)

these are the models(simplified)

```
class OrdersProducts(models.Model):

    products_attributes = fields.Many2one('orders.products.attributes', domain="[('order_product_id', '=', 0)]" )


    price_with_extra = fields.Float()

    @api.onchange('products_attributes.name') #This is not working either
    @api.onchange('products_attributes')#This is not triggered
    def _get_price_extra(self):
        for record in self:
            record.price_with_extra = record.products_attributes.product_with_extra
```

xml:

```
centralista_products_view.xml
<record id="orders_product_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">orders.products.tree.view</field>
    <field name="model">orders.products</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree editable="bottom">
            <field name="product_id" widget="many2one" string="Producto" attrs="{'readonly':[('pricelist_id', '=', False)]}"/>
            <field name="products_attributes" widget="many2one" string="Descripcion" options="{'no_quick_create': True, 'no_create': True, 'no_click': True}" context="{'product': product_id, 'price': price}"/>
            <field name="price_with_extra" string="Precio Unit." readonly="1"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

[@onchange](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/api.py#L134) only supports simple field names, dotted names (fields of relational fields `e.g. partner_id.tz`) are not supported and will be ignored.

You can make `product_with_extra` [related](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#related-fields) to `products_attributes.product_with_extra`.

If `product_with_extra` depends on another field value, use a [computed](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields) field.

Comment: thank you for answering, relating it does work great, but what i need is to update the product_with_extra whenever the products_attributes.name is changed, do you know anyway to do this?

Comment: Did you try to make it computed and depends on `products_attributes.name`?

Comment: yes, but it doesnt update on the fly, it only updates right after saving or refreshing the page